# Centered Navigation -- Sub Menus are Off-Center

Tags: html, css

I am working on this navigation bar and I noticed that I changed the tabs to be an even width apart from one another and now my sub menus don't line up with my main tabs. How can I get the sub menu to line up with their respective tab? My goal is to make the red rectangle that contains the sub menu to line up with the entire rectangle of it's parent tab. For example, I want "Members Group 1" to line up with "Members".

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: red;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, red));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:first-child>a,
#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Overview</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 1</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 2</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Files</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Bookmarks</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Your submenus (`#cssmenu .has-sub ul`) have an explicit width defined (`200px`), if you remove this width you should see the submenus align as expected. This is the `500,000` StackOverflow question tagged with `CSS` as of this writing - unfortunately, you don't get any extra points for though :(

Comment: holy... it actually is number 500,000. As for your question, you have text-align:centered on both elements, but as the texts have a different length, you get different results.

Comment: Number 500,000!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make width:100%;

```
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: red;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, red));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:first-child>a,
#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Overview</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 1</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 2</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Files</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Bookmarks</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really align these elements with each other with CSS, as they have `text-align:center` but different text lenghts. You'd have to make the `text-align` left, but of course then the navigation text will not be centered.

Here's a code snippet with the `text-align:left;`, but I think it looks better as it is.

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: red;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, red));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:first-child>a,
#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    }  
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a  {
padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Overview</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 1</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 2</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Files</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Bookmarks</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the submenu is already absolutely positioned, I would use the following trick to center it:

```
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: red;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, red));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, red 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:first-child>a,
#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #e60000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last>a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Overview</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 1</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 1.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Members Group 2</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Members Sub 2.5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Files</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Bookmarks</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: _" I want "Members Group 1" to line up with "Members"."_ I think she wants the words to line up vertically.... not center the sub-menu